# 名乗るｖｓ名付ける? Differences?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

What are the differences? They both seem to be about naming things.

Comment: Are you sure that 名乗る is "about naming"?

Answer (score 7):

- (～と)名乗る is to "to identify/introduce oneself (as ～)" or "tell one's (own) name". It's not about making a new name but about telling a name.

  > 太郎と名乗った。 He called himself Taro.
- (～と)名付ける is "to give someone/something a name" or simply "to name".

  > 太郎と名付けた。 I named (the baby) Taro.